# How to display a Labels 'Error on ErrorProvider1'

Tags: vb.net, winforms, errorprovider

### Goal

I want to display the text that I put in the Label's "Error on ErrorProvider1" attribute whenever I get an error. See the following label's attributes below.

[image: Error on ErrorProvider1]

I try to display the text in the red rectangle into my ErrorProvider1 `SetError(control, value)` function.

```
 If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Contains("'") Then
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(lblErr, ErrorProvider1.GetError(lblErr))
Else
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(lblErr, "")
End If
```

How can I retrieve the 'Error on ErrorProvider1' text from the lblErr to display it in the ErrorProvider1 `SetError` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are replacing the error message when nothing is wrong. As noted in your comment below, you are storing the localized error message in the label's `Tag`, so you can do the following:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Contains("'") Then
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(lblErr, lblErr.Tag)
Else
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(lblErr, "")
End If
```

You were correct to use `ErrorProvider1.GetError(Control)` to get the value. It's just that you're more than likely replacing it with an empty string before you were retrieving it.

Comment: Right, I understood that bit. But I'm trying to make my application localizable with french / english. Therefore I need a place to store information in both languages depending in which cultureinfo the user is on... I figured the `Tag` attribute would work to hold this information, I tested it and it works... If you wish to change your answer to include  `ErrorProvider.SetError(lblErr, lblErr.Tag)` where the error is placed, I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the information on how you were storing the string. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 8):

The ErrorProvider component is very awkward to use effectively.  It is fixable however, I'll give an example in C# that extends the component with some new capabilities:

- ShowError(Control ctl, bool enable) displays the text that you entered at design-time when the *enable* argument is true.  The easier-to-use version of SetError().
- HasErrors returns true if the any active warning icons are displayed.  Handy in your OK button's Click event handler.
- FocusError() sets the focus to the first control that has a warning icon, if any.  It returns *false* if no warnings are remaining.
- SetError() is a replacement of ErrorProvider.SetError().  You only need it if you add any controls after the form's Load event fired or if you need to modify the warning text.

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop it from the top of the toolbox onto the form.  The design-time behavior is identical.  Modestly tested.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

class MyErrorProvider : ErrorProvider {
    public void ShowError(Control ctl, bool enable) {
        // Easy to use version of SetError(), uses design-time text
        if (!enable) base.SetError(ctl, "");
        else {
            if (errors.ContainsKey(ctl)) base.SetError(ctl, errors[ctl]);
            else base.SetError(ctl, "No error text available");
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors {
        // True if any errors are present
        get {
            foreach (var err in errors)
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.GetError(err.Key))) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool FocusError() {
        // Set the focus to the first control with an active error
        foreach (var err in errors) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.GetError(err.Key))) {
                err.Key.Focus();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public new void SetError(Control ctl, string text) {
        // Use this only to add/modify error text after the form's Load event
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
            if (errors.ContainsKey(ctl)) errors[ctl] = text;
            else errors.Add(ctl, text);
        }
        base.SetError(ctl, text);
    }

    private void initialize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Preserve error text
        copyErrors(((Form)sender).Controls);
    }
    private void copyErrors(Control.ControlCollection ctls) {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
            var text = this.GetError(ctl);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
                errors.Add(ctl, text);
                base.SetError(ctl, "");
            }
            copyErrors(ctl.Controls);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<Control, string> errors = new Dictionary<Control, string>();

    // Plumbing to hook the form's Load event
    [Browsable(false)]
    public new ContainerControl ContainerControl {
        get { return base.ContainerControl; }
        set {
            if (base.ContainerControl == null) {
                var form = value.FindForm();
                if (form != null) form.Load += initialize;
            }
            base.ContainerControl = value;
        }
    }

    public override ISite Site {
        set {
            // Runs at design time, ensures designer initializes ContainerControl
            base.Site = value;
            if (value == null) return;
            IDesignerHost service = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (service == null) return;
            IComponent rootComponent = service.RootComponent;
            this.ContainerControl = rootComponent as ContainerControl;
        }
    }
}
```