# Find out which control caused ValidateChildren() to fail

Tags: winforms

When I call `myControl.ValidateChildren()` it returns false. How can I find out, which of the children failed to validate?

(I'm working with WinForms for the first time and am confronted with a huge pile of messy legacy code.)

Comment: You cannot get this from ValidateChildren(), it carefully avoids having to solve the which-is-most-invalid problem.  It simply fires the Validating event on the controls, it is up to you to use that event to give the user feedback.  Often skipped because it is grunty code and makes code more messy.  You can find a "better" ErrorProvider in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26262494/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant: That looks good, but I'm stuck with legacy code here and I'm trying to find out, why ValidateChildren() fails under certain circumstances. Would you implemnt the ErrorProvider first and then continue debugging?

Comment: No idea what "fails" might mean, it usually just returns *false*.  Happens when one of the Validating event handlers set e.Cancel to *true* because it is unhappy.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "returns false", i.e. which of the attached handlers sets e.Cancel to true.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you don't use the debugger.  Just set a breakpoint on the Validating event handlers, there should be a finite number of them.

Comment: I thought there might be a way to avoid that. I'm dealing with a big-ball-of-mud type legacy app. But OK, I'll have to dig through it the hard way then.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that seems to be to debug through the Validating event handlers. (See Hans' comment on the question.)

Answer (score 0):

With some Reflection it is possible to call the same internal functions that .net calls inside ValidateChildren.
This allows to retrieve the validation result of each control and find the one that causes the problem.
I wrote this small function for simple use:

```
Public Function GetFirstInvalidControl(container As ContainerControl) As Control
    Dim getStyle = GetType(Control).GetMethod("GetStyle", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    Dim isInvalid = GetType(Control).GetMethod("PerformControlValidation", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    Dim parents = New Queue(Of Control)
    parents.Enqueue(container)
    While parents.Any
        For Each control As Control In parents.Dequeue.Controls
            If CBool(getStyle.Invoke(control, {ControlStyles.Selectable})) AndAlso CBool(isInvalid.Invoke(control, {True})) Then
                Return control
            End If
            parents.Enqueue(control)
        Next
    End While
    Return Nothing
End Function
```